# How to create a tunnel to a remote AWS database after being connected in ssh to the Bastion host, all using in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, tunneling

I am trying to create a tunnel using **ssh2_tunnel()** to a remote AWS database, after being connected in ssh to the bastion host, via php, that has access to this remote MySql db.
Here is my actual code :

```
<?php
$ssh = ssh2_connect('domainofbastionhost', 22);
if (ssh2_auth_password($ssh,'myuserofthebastion','mypassofthebastion'){
    $tunnel = ssh2_tunnel($ssh,'xxxx.xxx.xxx.rds.amazonaws.com',3306);
    $stream_set_blocking($tunnel,true);
    //Everything works fine up to here
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=xxxx.xxx.xxx.rds.amazonaws.com;port=3306;dbname=myawsdbname','myusertoaccessmyawsdb','mypasstoaccessmyawsdb');
}
?>
```

Due to this $db line, I get on my localhost page "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out ....".

I have tried to connect to the db from the bastion host (by ssh) through my shell, everything works fine, I am greeted by the "Trying 'IPOFTHEAWSDB'... Connected to 'canonical domain name of the db'. Escape character is '^]'. ] 5.5.5-xx.x.xx-MariaDB-xxxxxxmysql_native_password", which means everything works fine. I even tried to connect directly to the aws db, and I get disconnected, which means that my bastion host is clearly whitelisted to access the db.
I think the problem is that when I want to create my new PDO object, I am not whitelisted to access the resource, which means I have to use that $tunnel variable somewhere. I have seen a few examples online of some users using, instead of my $db line :

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock;dbname=myawsdbname,'myusertoaccessmyawsdb','mypasstoaccessmyawsdb');
```

But this is not working, as I don't have access to this mysql.sock resource as it should be on the bastion host. It's using my own mysqld.sock from my local machine. But where is the $tunnel stream really stored ? I am not sure.

I am quite confused as if it is possible to do so, and if so, how.
If you know anything or find anything, please tell me, it would mean a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you have established a connection, via SSH, to the remote server, wouldn't the server be local? You might need the internal IP of the resource. Calling a command from the SSH Host will execute locally, so a call to the Public FQDN might not execute properly. Can you login to the console of the host and test the commands locally first, make sure they work, then test them in PHP remotely.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh2_tunnel()` returns a raw socket resource, which is not going to be usable by any MySQL client libraries. It does *not* create a tunnel like the `ssh` CLI binary does. Also Unix sockets and TCP are very different beasts, so I would suggest not trying to follow that thread any further.

I would suggest not attempting to establish the tunnel in the context of a PHP script at all, as every request will open another connection and tunnel, potentially creating a *lot* of overhead on the bastion's SSH server.

To create an SSH tunnel on the command line:

```
ssh -N -L 3306:your.rds.instance:3306 your_user@bastion.host
```

Now you should be able to connect via `127.0.0.1:3306` in your PHP script.

To close the connection/turn off the tunnel issue `ssh -O exit your_user@bastion.host`.

However, I would not suggest using SSH tunnels for anything intended to be unattended. This is because I have found SSH tunnels to be finnicky, and they do not re-establish themselves after an interruption unless you're using a wrapper script, which is another layer of kludge. So I would suggest this approach for local dev/remote access only.

For a persistent connection that you might want to use to connect services/websites over, I would suggest some form of VPN depending on your particular requirements. I believe you can also apply security groups to your RDS instances to simply whitelist connections from certain public IP addresses/networks, but use with caution.